# How can i both register blueprint and add that app to flask-admin

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin, blueprint

my Code:

__init__.py

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_admin import Admin
from flask_admin.contrib.sqla import ModelView
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('config')
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

from user.user import mod as user
from user.models import User as userModel

app.register_blueprint(user, url_prefix='/user')

admin = Admin(app, name='My app')
admin.add_view(ModelView(userModel, db.session, name='userAdmin'))
```

user.py:

```
from flask import Blueprint, json
from flask.views import MethodView

mod = Blueprint('user', __name__)

class UserAPI(MethodView):
    def get(self):
        users = [
            {'nickname': 'Chan'},
            {'nickname': 'Hzz'},
        ]
        return json.dumps(users)

mod.add_url_rule('/users/', view_func=UserAPI.as_view('users'))
```

models.py:

```
from app import db

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True)

    def __init__(self, username, email):
        self.username = username
        self.email = email

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<User %s>" % self.username
```

i have a blueprint in my user app, and i've registered it, but when i want to add this to my admin to manage the user data, it throws the below exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 2, in <module>
    from app import app
  File "/home/chenhj/flask/multiapp/app/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    admin.add_view(ModelView(userModel, db.session, name='chj'))
  File "/home/chenhj/.virtualenvs/multiapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_admin/base.py", line 526,     in add_view
    self.app.register_blueprint(view.create_blueprint(self))
  File "/home/chenhj/.virtualenvs/multiapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 62, in     wrapper_func
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/chenhj/.virtualenvs/multiapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 885, in     register_blueprint
    (blueprint, self.blueprints[blueprint.name], blueprint.name)
AssertionError: A blueprint's name collision occurred between <flask.blueprints.Blueprint object at 0x25e5d90> and <flask.blueprints.Blueprint object at 0x21b89d0>.  Both share the same name "user".  Blueprints that are created on the fly need unique names.
```

i am crazy about that

Comment: I think the answer in error log is more then clear... a lot of `user` names- just try to change some:)

Comment: yeah, i've fixed it, i've tried to rename the admin's name before and i failed, but the easiest way is to change the blueprint's name :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The collision is because you have a module name user and a blueprint called user. Rename the blueprint to user_blueprint. From the code it seems you have a folder called user, a module called user and a blueprint called user. You can avoid problems later on with some descriptive names. Otherwise it is just plain confusing.

Comment: Wow, i've tried lots of methods but this. it works! thanks

Comment: yeah, maybe all of the blueprint's name should add suffix '_blueprint' to make it unique! that's a good habit to coding

Answer (score 15):

If you have a blueprint that has a name of users already then your 'admin' blueprint for your admin users model view needs to be called something different.
You can achieve this with the endpoint var in ModelView
[Flask-Admin - ModelView](http://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/mod_contrib_sqla/#flask_admin.contrib.sqla.ModelView)

`admin.add_view(ModelView(Users, db.session, endpoint="users_"))`

Answer (score 4):

You can also override the admin blueprint names in a ModelView subclass:

```py
from flask_admin.contrib.sqla import ModelView

class AppModelView(ModelView):
    def create_blueprint(self, admin):
        blueprint = super(AppModelView, self).create_blueprint(admin)
        blueprint.name = '{}_admin'.format(blueprint.name)
        return blueprint

    def get_url(self, endpoint, **kwargs):
        if not (endpoint.startswith('.') or endpoint.startswith('admin.')):
            endpoint = endpoint.replace('.', '_admin.')
        return super(AppModelView, self).get_url(endpoint, **kwargs)
```